# (android) taking picture without saving

Tags: android

I used the code below to call camera in my android app.

With the code, I could take a picture and get the absolute path of the picture. 
But the problem is that the absolute path always pointed the internal storage. 
That is, the phone automatically saved the picture I took and I had to erase them one by one. 
I just want the absolute path so that I can turn it into a File object without saving in my storage or SD card. 
Maybe, I can temporarily save it in my allocated memory.

Is there any way to do this?

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if(requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA){

        imageUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("메시지", "uri = "+imageUri);

        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToNext();
        absolutePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA));

        Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a [thumbnail](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) of image **without store into internal memory or SD card**:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
         mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

For full sized image you need to define **shared file** (for example: cache file at SD card) and put it as `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
// camera app will save photo into sharedFileURI path
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, sharedFileURI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

See [Save the Full-size Photo article](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath) of official documentation for more info